# Function with nested forEach and for loop won't return false

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, foreach, return

I am doing an [algorithm challenge](https://edabit.com/challenge/HX5eEuKb7epMgsKsj) for practice in JS. I have a program that runs through a loop, and when the condition is met, the function should return false. However, when the condition is met, the return doesn't work and the function always ends up returning true.

```js
const isDiagonalLeftWristband = (band) => {
  band.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((item, x) => {
      for(let i = 0; (i < band[y].length - x) && (i < band.length - y); i++) {        
        if (band[y][x] !== band[y+i][x+i]) {
          console.log(false) //FALSE GETS OUTPUTTED MULTIPLE TIMES
          return false;
        }
      }
    })
  })
  return true;
}


const band3 = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["C", "Z", "B"],
  ["B", "C", "A"],
  ["A", "B", "C"]
];

console.log(isDiagonalLeftWristband(band3))
```

Output:

```
false //from console log
false //from console log
true //from function return statement
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return false` will only exit the `(item, x) => {}` anonymous function and not the `isDiagonalLeftWristband()` as you expect. After the two `forEach` are executed `isDiagonalLeftWristband()` will always `return true` on the end. You can use loops to avoid this problem.

```js
const isDiagonalLeftWristband = (band) => {
  for (let [y, row] of band.entries()) {
    for (let [x, item] of row.entries()) {
      for(let i = 0; (i < band[y].length - x) && (i < band.length - y); i++) {        
        if (band[y][x] !== band[y+i][x+i]) {
          console.log(false) //FALSE GETS OUTPUTTED MULTIPLE TIMES
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}

const band3 = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["C", "Z", "B"],
  ["B", "C", "A"],
  ["A", "B", "C"]
];

console.log(isDiagonalLeftWristband(band3))
```

`forEach` is not designed to terminate early. It will always iterate over all the elements. (it's in the name :)). From the MDN documentation:

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool.
>
> Early termination may be accomplished with:
>
> ```
> A simple for loop
> A for...of / for...in loops
> Array.prototype.every()
> Array.prototype.some()
> Array.prototype.find()
> Array.prototype.findIndex()
> ```
>
> Array methods: every(), some(), find(), and findIndex() test the array
>   elements with a predicate returning a truthy value to determine if
>   further iteration is required.

You can instead use one of the suggested functions designed to test the elements of an array with a predicate. `every()` tests if all elements of an array pass some test; which is, at least semantically, what you need.

```js
const isDiagonalLeftWristband = (band) => {
  return band.every((row, y) => {
    return row.every((item, x) => {
      for(let i = 0; (i < band[y].length - x) && (i < band.length - y); i++) {        
        if (band[y][x] !== band[y+i][x+i]) {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return true;    
     });
  });
}

const band3 = [
  ["A", "B", "C"],
  ["C", "B", "B"],
  ["B", "C", "A"],
  ["A", "B", "C"]
];

console.log(isDiagonalLeftWristband(band3))
```

Comment: This has solved my problem, but for the sake of learning, is there a way to make the function work with forEach? Naoufal's answer is a possible solution, but like he pointed out, his solution won't exit after finding the first false.

Comment: @NicholasNewman I've edited my answer to answer your question. In short, there is no sensible way to terminate a forEach early.

Answer (score 0):

the `return false;` statments only return the value to the function it belongs to, which is

```
(item, x) => {
      for(let i = 0; (i < band[y].length - x) && (i < band.length - y); i++) {        
        if (band[y][x] !== band[y+i][x+i]) {
          console.log(false) //FALSE GETS OUTPUTTED MULTIPLE TIMES
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

your code must work in a way that it can return the false to the main function, you can use this approach:

```
const isDiagonalLeftWristband = (band) => {
  let returnValue = true;
  band.forEach((row, y) => {
    row.forEach((item, x) => {
      for(let i = 0; (i < band[y].length - x) && (i < band.length - y); i++) {        
        if (band[y][x] !== band[y+i][x+i]) {
          console.log(false) //FALSE GETS OUTPUTTED MULTIPLE TIMES
          returnValue = false;
          // return false;
        }
      }
    })
  })
  return returnValue;
}
```

What domondo suggested is way better because the function exists once it finds the first `false`